# confusion about purrr::walk

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to catch up with the purrr::walk, but feel little bit confused. Please find the toy example, and advise where I go wrong.

```
library(purrr)
# ordinary lapply
lp = 1
lp2 <- 
  lapply(1:10, function(c) {
    lp <<- lp + c
    print(lp)
  }) %>% invisible

lp # 56
lp2 # a list up to 56

# purrr::map
mp = 1
mp2 <- 
  map(.x = 1:10,
      .f = function(c) {
              mp <<- mp + c
              print(mp[[1]])
           }
  ) %>% invisible
mp # 56
mp2 # a list up to 56

wk = 1
wk2 <- 
  walk(.x = 1:10, 
       .f = function(c) {
         wk <<- wk +c
         print(wk)
         return(wk)
       })
wk #56
wk2 # a vector up to 10
    # that confuses me, shouldn't it be as much as wk2?
```

By the way, with such short example, it doesn't show much difference in performance

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(lp2, mp2, wk2, times = 10000)

#> microbenchmark(lp2, mp2, wk2, times = 10000)
#Unit: nanoseconds
# expr min lq    mean median uq   max neval
#  lp2  39 47 55.1047     49 56 15738 10000
#  mp2  40 47 59.2899     49 56 15661 10000
#  wk2  39 47 57.4763     50 56 15629 10000
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html), `walk` is used for the side-effects of `f` and returns the input. In your example, the input is a vector of length 10. The `invisible` calls you have in the first two examples don't force the return of their inputs as `walk` does. You can also check out the source code.. this should help you understand.

Comment: yes, you are right. I should have read the doc more closely. Many thanks.

Comment: No worries. My goto is the documentation and if that doesn't go so well, I look at the source. The `tidyverse` docs are generally pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @JosephWood, it turns out that I didn't read the doc close enough.
I love th community!

as @andrew_reece suggests, here is my understanding from this case.

purrr::walk is as named, it proceeds step by step. What it concerns is to go through all the steps assigned. As to the result, the result is the `side effect` happening when the function walks.

Therefore, the return value simply announces "I'd finished the steps you asked for".

```
wk = 1
wk2 <- 
  walk(.x = 1:10, 
       .f = function(c) {
         wk <<- wk +c   ## do something while walking,
                        ## and pass out the result to tell what you've done.
         print(wk)
         return(wk)
       })
wk #56  <- the final result of the side effect.
wk2 # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    # I'd finished the 10 steps you asked.
```

purrr::map, and its siblings, as apply family, are focusing on doing this for certain times, in certain manners, and returns the values it obtains when it `marches` forward.

Comment: Glad to hear you found an answer to your question.  Would you consider adding the actual solution to your coding question in this answer?  As it is, it's more of a comment than a real answer.  Others who come to this post to learn may not immediately understand how to solve their own problems, without a clear coding solution.